# Uninstall the Mg editor and use angular/cli properly

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to make a new project using "ng new client" but this command open a editor like below.[image]

Comment: did you found any solution? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 30):

I think you were looking for following:

```
sudo apt remove mg ng-common
npm install -g @angular/cli
```